# the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type error

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type error this statement error in  " sda.Fill(dt);"

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // getData();
    // getDatas();`enter code here`
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PGAConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

    //  string sqlquery = "  Select * from tbl_registration where registration_date between '" + txtfromDate.Text + "'and'" + txtToDate.Text + "'";
    //string sqlquery ="Select* from tbl_registration where registration_date between '" + txtfromDate.Text + "'and'" + txtToDate.Text + "'";
    //string sqlquery = "Select* from tbl_registration where registration_date between '2018/12/10' and '2018/12/13'";
    //string sqlquery = "  Select * from tbl_registration";
     SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("getuserdatewisereport", sqlconn);
    //SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery , sqlconn);
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlconn.Open();
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", txtfromDate.Text);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", txtToDate.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    gridData.DataSource = dt;
    gridData.DataBind();
    sqlconn.Close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual SQL being run here?

Comment: If the `startdate` and `enddate` parameters are meant to be datetime parameters, I'd recommend converting explicitly *in the code* rather than letting it happen at some point that's harder for you to control.

Answer (score 1):

Before you pass the datetime, you should parse it into a DateTime variable and pass this to the stored procedure.

```
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse(txtfromDate.Text);
DateTime enddate = DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text);

sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
```

Comment: Thanks you  for sebastin solving issue.